# FPDF A4 size is not printed

Tags: php, fpdf

I use FPDF for PDF generation in my project. I want to generate A4 size page and I use following line.

```php
$fpdf = new PDF('P','mm',array(595.28,841.89));
$fpdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');
```

I generate the PDF using this code and I got print out. Then I realize that the page size is not fit for the A4.
Can somebody help me on this regard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you pass the wrong default page size (595.28mm by 841.89mm) to the FPDF constructor, which by the way should be `FDPF`. [A4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A4_paper#A_series) is 210mm by 297mm if in portrait mode.

So you should call the constructor this way:

```php
$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
```

or

```php
$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm',array(210,297));
```

After that you can omit the page size parameter when calling `AddPage()`.

Here is a complete *Hello World* example:

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was a little confused, as I wanted to add A6 paper to FPDF and stumpled upon this post.

FPDF defines:

```
$this->StdPageSizes = array(
    'a3'=>array(841.89,1190.55),
    'a4'=>array(595.28,841.89),
    'a5'=>array(420.94,595.28),
    'letter'=>array(612,792),
    'legal'=>array(612,1008)
);
```

So I assume there the authors `595.28,841.89` came from.

But those are actually pt and not mm.

So the easiest way to add an A4 paper was already shown my @peterm:

```
$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4'); // way 1
$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm',[210, 297]); // way 2 using mm units.
```

Alternatively you could use points (see fpdf.php class property `k` for scale factor)

```
$pdf = new FPDF('P','pt',[595.28,841.89]); // way 3 using pt units.
```

As eg A6 format is not defined the following code would throw an exception:

```
$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A6'); // throws  FPDF error: Unknown page size: a6
```

To add more page formats for fpdf you can use the following examples:

```
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', [841, 1189]);    // A0
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', [594, 841]);     // A1
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', [420, 594]);     // A2
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', [297, 420]);     // A3
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', [210, 297]);     // A4
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', [148, 210]);     // A5
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', [105, 148]);     // A6
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', [74, 105]);      // A7
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', [52, 74]);       // A8
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', [37, 52]);       // A9
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', [26, 37]);       // A10
```